# Mongodb e Redis no mesmo servidor

Tags: php, node.js, servidor, mongodb, redis

Estou planejando um sistema que utiliza o Mongodb para leitura dados e o Redis para compartilhamento de sessão entre PHP e Nodejs. Há algum problema ter o Redis e o Mongodb rodando no mesmo servidor, visto que ambos armazenam dados na memória?

Comment: MongoDB, nao armazena em memoria. De qqr forma eles usam portas diferentes, entao fique tranquilo.

Comment: Obrigado por responder Ecil, mas a documentação o mongodb diz o seguinte: MongoDB uses memory mapped files for managing and interacting with all data. MongoDB memory maps data files to memory as it accesses documents. Data that isn’t accessed is not mapped to memory. você pode dar uma olhada nesse link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/

Answer (score 2):

creio que não há problema nenhum. É só deixar a porta deles diferente (por padrão já é).
Não sei se estou certo, mas o Mongodb não armazena na memória, Memcached e Redis armazena. O mongo pode fazer algumas operações e armazenar na memória por um tempo pra agilizar mas ele tem um arquivo que é seu banco de dados.